# Trace execution

Tags: go, trace

I am working on a project which involves multiple subprojects and lots of different execution paths. I carefully read the code multiple times but still, I am not sure if the code takes my desired path. Now I am looking for a way to find the execution path of my executable (trace it); initially, I thought of adding lots of print statements but then I wondered if there is a simpler solution to this problem.

Comment: This is much too broad for us to help. Instead of a simple print statement, try something like [debug.PrintStack](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#PrintStack)

Comment: The most common way of tracing an execution path would be using a stepwise debugger like [Delve](https://github.com/go-delve/delve). If you're using VS Code, it has a built-in Delve integration in the Go plugin.